# Image load not working with IE 8 or lower

Tags: javascript, image, internet-explorer

I am aiming to check if image has been loaded successfully. It has been working well in modern browsers but IE8 or 7 it is a terrible issue. Here is a sample code:

```
var img = new Image(),
    url = 'http://something.com/images/something.gif';

    $(img).attr('src', url).load(function() {
        if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
            alert('broken image!');
        } 
        else {
            alert('successfully loaded');
        }
    }
```

Anyone has any idea to work around with this issue? Thanks in advace!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You HAVE to set the `onload` handler BEFORE you set the `.src` value.

In some versions of IE, if the image is in the browser cache, the load event will be fired immediately when the `.src` value is set.  If your load handler is not already in place, you will miss that event.

Also, `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` are NOT supported in older versions of IE so they will always be undefined.  And, you should use `onerror` and `onabort` to catch the error conditions.

There's no need to use jQuery for this.  You can just do this:

```
var img = new Image(),

img.onload = function() {
    alert("loaded successfully");
}
img.onerror = img.onabort = function() {
    alert("broken image");
}
// only set .src AFTER event handlers are in place
img.src = 'http://something.com/images/something.gif';
```

Comment: In this case, if image is already loaded will it load again or it will load from cache?

Comment: If you specify the same URL that has been previously loaded, the browser will load it from cache.  That's the point of the cache.

Answer (score 3):

If the image is broken, then `onload` event won't be fired, instead, the `onerror` event will be fired. So you need to do like this:

```
var img = new Image(),
url = 'http://something.com/images/something.gif';

img.onload = function() {
  alert('successfully loaded');
};

img.onerror = function() {
  alert('broken image!');
};

$(img).attr('src', url);
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$(img).load(function() {
  alert('successfully loaded');
}).error(function() {
  alert('broken image!');
}).attr('src', url);
```

Comment: Thanks but I wonder why in Chrome and Firefox work well and I get alert when image is loaded successfully. Let's say if image is Ok you have any more suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to the real world of browser inconsistencies. Cope with them.

Answer (score 1):

```
var url="http://something.com/images/something.gif",
    img=new Image;
img.onload=img.onerror=function(ev){
  if(ev.type=="load")alert("successfully loaded");
  else if(ev.type=="error")alert("error loading");
}
img.src=url;
// If image is cached then no `onload` or `onerror` can occur.
if(img.complete){
  alert("successfully loaded");
  img.onload=img.onerror=null;
}
```